# Gwt process id which run using runtime.getExec("<tcl file>") function

Tags: java, servlets, tcl

I need to execute a tcl file which gives output util we stop the process from java. So I use

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("< tcl file >");
```

I need to get the process id (PID) to stop the process.I can run that same tcl file multiple times, so I can't get pid using getting name of executing file. Give me some methods to get process id using JAVA when running a external program.

output of ps command :

```
25014 pts/0    00:00:00 tclfile
29998 pts/0    00:00:09 tclfile
30866 pts/0    00:00:00 tclfile
```

Each instance is different I need to stop only specified process at a time, can't terminate all by killall -9 tclfile command .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pid is not exposed to Java, since Java is platform-agnostic and pids are platform-specific. So you aren't going to be able to get the actual pid without using native code, sorry.

But if you just want a handle to the child process which you can later kill, you can do that in pure Java. The [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object has methods `destroy()` (which kills the process) and `waitFor()` (which waits for it to exit). In Java 8 it also has [`isAlive()` and `destroyForcibly()` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

OK, after poking around on the net to find source code for `ProcessImpl` in various JREs, it looks like on Windows `ProcessImpl` has a field [`handle`](https://code.google.com/p/jdk-source-code/source/browse/trunk/jdk5.0_src/j2se/src/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java?r=19#33) which presumably is the Win32 handle returned by `CreateProcess`, and on Linux `UNIXProcess` has a field [`pid`](https://code.google.com/p/jdk-source-code/source/browse/trunk/jdk5.0_src/j2se/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java.linux?r=19#24) which appears to be the process ID. If you wanted to be really hacky (and unsupported, and potentially tied to a specific JDK implementation, etc. -- all the usual caveats apply), you could potentially access those fields by reflection if you need to.

That said, a better solution would be to write the native code yourself, or else delegate to a helper process (e.g. in bash like Donal Fellows' answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the process ID from the `Process` object; it knows it (strictly, it's known by an object inside of a class that isn't part of the public API) but won't tell you. The simplest method of getting the PID turns out to be to get the subprocess to tell you that value by writing it to its standard out (or standard error, but that's less common) as its first action. You then can just read a line, parse the integer out of it, and there you go.

Getting Tcl scripts to print their PID is trivial. Just put this line in:

```tcl
puts [pid]
# Or: puts stdout [pid]
```

If you can't change the Tcl script, you can use a shell script trick to wrap it in something that writes the value:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
# exec, in bash, *replaces* the process implementation with another program
exec tclsh "$@"
```